# Coleman ct200u ex minibike starts, then stalls

Tags: engine, carburetor

Have problem with my Coleman ct200u ex that is driving me batty.

It starts, runs for about 15 seconds, then dies, almost as if it ran out of gas suddenly or the kill switch was pressed.  Will not start immediately.  If I wait about 30 seconds, it will start right up, run for 15 seconds, and repeats stall.  Tried playing with choke, carb settings, to no avail.  Starts, runs 15 seconds, then dies.

First I thought it might be a clogged carburetor.  Cleaned it (no go), then replaced it (same problem).  Then thought fuel was not getting through line, so replaced fuel line and added fresh fuel, changed spark plug, cleaned air filter.

Could this be electrical?  Dies almost as if kill switch was engaged.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Sal

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! To my thinking, this is most definitely a fueling issue, so you were on the right track. Will it run with the choke on? Also, have you checked to ensure the petcock from the fuel tank is not only on all the way, but is also draining fuel properly? Could be it isn't allowing enough fuel out of the tank (assuming it has a fuel shutoff on the tank).

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. New Ignition coil worked for me. The ignition coil wire was burned on the head under the plastic engine cover

Answer (score 0):

Change out the spark plug. Most likely a hairline crack in the porcelain and is grounding out as soon as it gets hot.